# How to add custom widgets in wxglade

Tags: python, wxpython, wxglade

I have an app that I made with wxglade. I've added a mediacontrol to be able to play mp3:s. Without the mediacontrol the app starts with a frame that is 800x600px. But when I add the mediacontrol, the frame is very small. I believe this is because I've not added it to a sizer. But do I have to do that? The mediacontrol isn't supposed to show anything anyways.

So, my question is, how do I add a mediacontrol to my app  without **(a)** breaking the possibility of updating the gui with wxglade and **(b)** losing the ability to start with the right size?

If I can I would not put anything between the `# Begin wxglade` and `# End wxglade`. Because then it will be destroyed if I change my gui with wxglade (according to earlier tests anyway).

Edit: The code snippet I supplied doesn't add anything of interest. I also edited the question to be more clear so other people with the same question can find this answer.

Comment: Question and answer will find more readers with a more appropriate title. I propose: "How to add custom widgets in wxglade" or something alike

Comment: Your right. It was a very good answer that worked out great for me so it deserves to be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A fast trick:**

1. In the place your widget should be, insert an `wx.Panel` with wxGlade
   and give it the name `mymediactrl` instead of, for example, `mypanel`.
2. Then, after you have your script generated, import (or insert the code of)
   your MediaControl class in a place allowed (non-writable) by wxglade
   (in the space outside the sections delimited by '*# begin wxGlade*' and
   '*# end wxGlade*' tags).
3. Finally, modify manually the `mymediactrl=wx.Panel(...)` line in the script with your 
   `mymediactrl = MediaControl(...)` line. Note: This line must be maintained manually when
   you modify your GUI because wxglade will rewrite it.

**The correct way:**

You can use the CustomWidget widget of the wxglade widget set.
This is the recommended method if you have experience with wxglade.

[image]

**The Pro method:**

You can add your own custom widget to the wxglade widget set.
You have some example and a tutorial of [how to do it here](https://sites.google.com/site/lvmarcoux/Home/wxglade)

Comment: Ok. It seems like we need to put request to the wxglade guys that we want a way to add custom widgets ;) But thanks, I look into it soon :-)

Comment: I feel really stupid for not checking that up. I tried googling wxglade custom widget But did'nt find anything. But I really should have looked more closely to the buttons... A great thanks!

Comment: I think I stick to the "correct way". Don't feel "pro" enough for adding a custom widget to the widget set ;)

Comment: Sorry, I am busy with other things and I had to write my answer by pieces... Think now the answer is complete

Comment: And that is why I LOVE Stack Overflow. Good (and often complete answers) combined with fast answers!

Comment: Btw, how does one handle imports when using CustomWidget? I'm trying to show wx.lib.agw.knobctrl.KnobCtrl, and preview fails with "Problem previewing gui: 'module' object has no attribute 'agw'" ... [wxGlade / Mailing Lists: custom widget - import statement support](https://sourceforge.net/p/wxglade/mailman/message/26365536/) says I should add `import this` in "Extra Code", but that doesn't work...